# Reading jpg metadata with javax.imageio sometimes throw JFIF APP0 must be first marker after SOI

Tags: metadata, jpeg, javax.imageio

I have to set watermark on image (bytes[] original image), i can't use a ImageIO.read() because this method ignore metadata that i also need in future processes, so i had to ImageReader. This method work nice for some pictures and for some doesn't (both of them are .JPG)

```
private InputStream createWatermark(byte[] bytes, Long position) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(255);
    ImageOutputStream ios;
    try {
        ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
        ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix(getExtensionFromImage(bytes)).next();
        reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
        IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

        BufferedImage bi = reader.read(0);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String watermark = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, bi.getWidth() / 45));
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        Rectangle2D rect = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(watermark, g2d);

        int x = getX(position, bi, rect);
        int y = getY(position, bi);

        g2d.drawString(watermark, x, y);

        Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(getExtensionFromImage(bytes));
        ImageWriter writer = iter.next();
        writer.setOutput(ios);

        ImageWriteParam iwParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        iwParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

        IIOImage image = new IIOImage(bi, null, metadata);

        writer.write(null, image, iwParam);
        writer.dispose();

        bytes = os.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
}
```

javax.imageio.IIOException: JFIF APP0 must be first marker after SOI

on line: 
IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

Comment: getExtensionFromImage method returns image extension (png, jpg..)

Comment: The JFIF (JPEG File Interchange Format) spec requires the JFIF APP0 marker to be the first marker after the SOI marker. Some of the files you have doesn't follow the spec. The standard `JPEGImageReader` is a little picky about this, even if the file is otherwise fully readable. You can try using [my `JPEGImageReader` plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg), which tries to be more lenient about malformed input. If not, attach one of the images that fail, and I'll look into it. :-)